# Query limited data in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application that retrieves the posts from firebase. The problem is I want to retrieve the first 20 posts and show in a table.  When a user clicks the next button, it will retrieve the next 20 posts and show and so on.

I know firebase provides the following methods

1. queryLimitedToFirst
2. queryLimitedToLast
3. queryStartingAtValue
4. queryEndingAtValue
5. queryEqualToValue

But how do I use them in conjunction to retrieve the desired results like I want?

Here is the structure of the data I have:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+pagination

Answer (score 0):

You should order query by some property (I usually use timestamp). This organises your orders from latest to oldest. When you have them ordered you should limit them:

`queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: UInt(limit))`

As you can see we can limit results to whatever number we like. You can use this to read your posts each time for 20 results more.
So the first time you call it with a limit of 20, next time with a limit of 40, etc. Keep in mind that this will return posts that were already returned in the previous call.

Instead you could combine it with `queryStartingAtValue` and use your last post tiemstamp - this will "skip" your previous results and return only 20 posts you need.

This is just an idea but I think it should work like expected.